# Resolving the resolved promise again

Tags: angularjs, promise

I'm using $q of AngularJS, when I create a single promise and that promise is already resolved, can it be resolved again? I don't know if this is possible but if not is there a way that I can resolve the same promise again and again. I was thinking of using the notify way but I don't know if there are other ways to do this.

Comment: To "resolve a promise again" makes no sens. You can eventually resend the same request, for example, but that's totally different. What do you want to do exactly?

Comment: Richeve, it depends what you are trying to do. As others have correctly pointed out, a resolved (or rejected) promise cannot change state. However, it you want to re-access the value with which a promise was resolved (or rejected) that's a completely different matter, eg `myPromise.done(myfunc1); .... myPromise.done(myfunc2)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [**Mastering Web Application Development with Angularjs**, by Kozlowski and Bacon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1782161821), Chapter 3 "Communicating with a Back-end Server", section "The Promise API with $q":

> A promise that was resolved or rejected once can't change its state.
>
> There is only one  chance of providing promised results. In other words **it is not** possible to:
>
> - Resolve a rejected promise
> - Resolve an already resolved promise with a different result
> - Reject a resolved promise
> - Reject a rejected promise with a different rejection reason
>
> Those rules are rather intuitive.
> For example, it wouldn't make much sense if we could be called back with the information that there are problems with a pizza order delivery after a pizza was successfully delivered (and probably eaten!).

If you provide more code and we can understand better what you are trying to do we might be able to help you.

Comment: If you need multiple values from a promise, a promise is probably not what you need. You might look into Functional Reactive Programming with something like Rx.js or Irakli “Gozala”’s reducers https://github.com/Gozala/reducers

Answer (score 0):

what I simply did was reinitialize promise again like so:

```
var appReadyDeferred = $q.defer();
this.prepareAppReadyDeffered = function() {
  appReadyDeferred = $q.defer();
};
this.appReady = function() {
  return appReadyDeferred.promise;
};
this.appResolve = function() {
  appReadyDeferred.resolve();
};
this.appDeferr = function() {
  appReadyDeferred.reject();
};
```

So I can use

```
someService.appReady().then(function() {
   // some code
});
```

And reinit it using

```
someService.prepareAppReadyDeffered();
```

I'm not sure this is the best possible resolution but it seems to work.